# What is the difference between bootstrap sampling vs multinomial distribution?

Tags: sampling, bootstrap, multinomial-distribution

I feel like bootstrap sampling and multinomial distribution sampling are equivalent. Just want to verify whether my understanding is correct.

Say my data is `1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3`.

Multinomial distribution sampling would be sample 7 observations from a multinomial distribution (2/7, 4/7, 1/7). Isn't bootstrap sampling with replacement essentially the same thing because every time we draw an observation from the data, the chance of getting each value is also (2/7, 4/7, 1/7)? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can think of it as drawing from a multinomial distribution. In fact, when I code bootstrap procedures from scratch, I do exactly that over the indices of my data.

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(2022)
N <- 100
B <- 1000
X <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, 0.9, 0.9, 1), 2, 2))
for (i in 1:B){
  
  idx <- sample(seq(1, N, 1), N, replace = T) # This is multinomial sampling
                                              # with each index "category"
                                              # having an equal probability
                                                
  X_boot <- X[idx, ] # Select the indices
    
  # Then do something with X_boot, such as calculating the correlation
}
```

Since you have duplicated values in your `1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3`, drawing uniformly over the indices is in some sense equivalent to doing a multinomial draw with $P(1)=2/7$, $P(2) = 4/7$, and $P(3)=1/7$. There's this issue where the values `1`, `2`, and `3` are numbers and not categories, so it is debatable if this is multinomial, but this technicality can be resolved by doing a distribution like:

$$
P(\text{Pick 1 and add it to the bootstrap sample}) = 2/7\\
P(\text{Pick 2 and add it to the bootstrap sample}) = 4/7\\
P(\text{Pick 3 and add it to the bootstrap sample}) = 1/7\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

The are many variants of the [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) and, on the surface, the *nonparametric* or *re-sampling* bootstrap has a similarity to drawing from a multinomial distribution. See @Dave's answer.

The bootstrap uses the plug-in principle: we replace an unknown distribution $F$ by an estimate $\widehat{F}$. There are many possible choices for $\widehat{F}$. If $\widehat{F}$ is a parametric distribution, then the bootstrap is *parameteric* or *model-based*.

Moreover, as @Tim exaplains in [Bootstrapping and ECDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466809/bootstrapping-and-ecdf), the bootstrap refers to the entire statistical procedure for estimating uncertainties. That is, once you've sampled $n$ times with replacement from the original dataset of size $n$, the bootstrap also explains how to do inference (estimate standard errors, calculate p-values, compute confidence intervals, etc.)

So drawing an analogy (actually, false equivalence) between bootstrapping and sampling from a multinomial distribution will take your understanding of bootstrapping methods only so far.

B. Efron and T. Hastie. *Computer Age Statistical Inference Algorithms, Evidence, and Data Science* (2021) It's freely [available online](https://hastie.su.domains/CASI/).